# Set pagination in product review tab in magento2

Tags: magento2.1.0

I want to set pagination in product review tab.
So if I have 30 reviews for particular product, then in reviews tab I want the pagination from 1 to 5 with next and previous buttons and in all pages I want to show only 5 review/page.

On this path **vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Product/View** I got block file **ListView.php**. File code is below.

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();

    $toolbar = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_review_list.toolbar');
    if ($toolbar) {
        $toolbar->setCollection($this->getReviewsCollection());
        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Above is the review collection code so how to change this code so I can set pagination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Magento 2 Default provide Pagination in Review Tab. If you want to Set Limit in review than change in below file.  
   vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Pager.php

find Below Code in Pager.php

 protected $_availableLimit = [10 => 10, 20 => 20, 50 => 50];

Replace With 

 protected $_availableLimit = [5 => 5, 10 => 10, 25 => 25];
```

It's Working to Set Limit in Review Tab.

Answer (score 1):

All of the solutions above assume that you will never update, or reinstall your magento.

You shouldn't edit anything in vendor directory. Ever!

There are better solutions. In your specific case, you can use that in if statement provided above.

```
$toolbar->setAvailableLimit([5=>5,10=>10,15=>15]);
```

Assuming that your collection still haven't been loaded.

If it have been, I would recommend adding plugin overwritting your default layout.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to override block file `/vendor/magento/module-theme/Block/Html/Pager.php` and find code like this:

```
protected $_availableLimit = [10 => 10, 20 => 20, 50 => 50];
```

Then you need to add extra limit value (which is 5 in your case) like this:

```
protected $_availableLimit = [5 => 5, 10 => 10, 20 => 20, 50 => 50];
```

Please let me know if you have any question.

Comment: this will change the pagination for everything.

Comment: @Marius I only want to set pagination for product reviews tab. how can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried it or not?

Comment: I don't think it will change pagination for every thing because for products there is setting in admin panel and when limit parameter value is set from admin panel (for products), then it will not affect in other places.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora if I want to add pagination in product reviews tab only then I need to change in above code that I added in my question on anywhere else?

Comment: Magento 2 provided pagination by default for reviews also. You don't have to add any code to show pagination. When reviews are more than your set limit, then pagination will start showing by default.
By default pagination starts showing after 10 reviews.

Comment: Do you know that how to by default 2nd page open in product review tab when page load?

Answer (score 0):

For example you want pagination of 5 per page.
Make these changes.

in app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\UpdatePagerClass" />
```

and in app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/UpdatePagerClass.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager;

class UpdatePagerClass extends Pager
{
    /**
     * Retrieve pager limit
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAvailableLimit()
    {
        $limits=[];
        for($i=4; $i<=100; $i+=5){
            $limits[$i]=$i;
        }
        return $limits;
    }
}
```